# SQL Query Not Working In SQL Server MS

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am building an application on Windows Forms using SQL Server Management Studio.
I already learned basics of SQL from w3Schools Ms SQL Engine. Now When I am trying To Use Join in SQL Server Management Studio, its throwing an exception.

Here's My Query:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerName;
```

The query is working fine with w3 Ms SQL engine but not with SQL Server managment studio.

The Exception/Error is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'CustomerName'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'CustomerName'.

Both Columns i.e `CustomerID` and `CustomerName` are present in Tables.
What am I doing wrong here?

**SOLVED**
Using Fully Qualified Names Fixed The Issue.
Thanks For Help :)

Comment: Are you definitely connected to the correct database?

Comment: Surely, Other Simple Queries Like "select * from Orders" are working just fine with the Application.

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle showing the issue here: http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: Try the same query with fully qualified table names, i.e. DBname.schemaname.tablename for both Customers and Orders, and see if you get the same problem. E.g. DWH.dbo.Customers or equivalent for your situation.

Comment: There's no reason for a query as simple as the above to work in one application and not in another, if you are connected to the same database, and connected as the same login. Thus, something is different, hence my question. If you run the following SQL (in SSMS) is anything returned? `SELECT c.[name] as ColumnName, t.[name] AS TableName FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys,columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE c.[name] = 'CustomerName';`

Comment: can you post your output of SELECT * FROM Customers (maybe just include one or two lines of data)

Comment: Can you add the database structure of Customers?

Comment: SOLVED Using Fully Qualified Names Fixed The Issue. Thanks For Help :)

Comment: Can you please mark the answer correct in your other question?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the local IntelliSense cache in SQL Server Management Studio.
You have the option under "Edit" menu. "Edit --> IntelliSense --> Refresh Local Cache"
This will resolve your problem.

Thanks,
Raghava